# How do I change the css of a rectangle to a gradient in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, fill

So basically I'm working on a gradient generator but the gradient just won't appear. I currently have

```
<rect id="preview" class="preview" width="300" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)" />
```

in the html and

```
document.getElementById("preview").style.property = "fill: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,121,103,1) 50%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);"
```

in the javascript (should give a nice green-to-teal gradient) but it just doesn't work, it shows black and thats it, no idea what to do and how to fix it

Comment: SVG does not suport linear-gradient CSS, you'd need to defined the linearGradient via a linearGradient element and point the fill to that. Does the gradient generator not have an option to produce SVG linearGradients?

Comment: @RobertLongson what do you mean? (with both the lineargradient thing and the last question)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#gradients

Answer (score 0):

As Robert said, for now you need to use SVG `<linearGradient>` elements.

```js
document.getElementById("preview").style = "fill: url(#grad);"
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(2,0,36,1)"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="rgba(9,121,103,1)"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(0,212,255,1)"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect id="preview" class="preview" width="300" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```